# Xcode10.0 (10A255) import intent xx.h occur mistakes

Tags: xcode10

Each time the Xcode will crash while I import header files（xx.h), I cannot use it.

pod version: 1.6.0.beta.1
mac os version：10.13.6 (17G65)

Answer (score 0):

Xcode --> File --> Workspace Settings --> Build System --> Legacy Build System

It works, but I don't know why.